# Compare password to a given set of passwords

Tags: c, string, pointers, string-comparison

I have got an assignment from uni which mentions that I have to compare a given set of passwords to the password given by the user. The set of passwords are predetermined in the question as follows

```c
const char *passwd[NUM_PASSWDS] = {
    "123foo", "bar456", "bla_blubb"
};
```

and has to be compared with input from user...

So I have written my code as follows;

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_PASSWDS 3

const char *passwd[NUM_PASSWDS] = {
    "123foo", "bar456", "bla_blubb"
};

int pwdquery(char pass[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (passwd[i] == pass[i]) {
            return printf("correct");
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char a[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("Please enter password");
        scanf("%s", a);
    }
    pwdquery(a);
}
```

When I tried running my code, it shows an error...

Thank you for your time

Comment: When asking for debugging help you should provide a [mre] which includes the full error you're getting.

Comment: There are multiple problems in your code. The first is that you mix comparing strings to characters (`passwd` is an array of strings while `pass` is an array of characters). The possibly second problem is that you can't compare strings using `==`. Another problem is that you do not check all the passwords in the `passwd` array. A fourth problem is that you need to return a value if the loop in `pwdquery` ends without a match. A fifth problem is that you input three strings, storing them in the same single character array `a`, each input overwriting the previous.

Comment: All in all I think you need to take a few steps back, and refresh the chapters and sections about arrays, pointers and strings in your text-books or other learning material. Then sit down with pen and paper, and write down in plain simple normal sentences what you want to do, and create a step by step list of instructions (still plain sentences) to solve the problem.

Comment: It's okay for an exercise, but for real world, don't put plaintext passwords in code. They can be read easily from the binary. Use a cryptographic hash and salt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare string you need to [strcmp](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) function.
[printf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm) returns number of character printed. You should return fixed value on success or failure of password match. In my example I'm returning 1 in case of password match or 0 in case of no-password match.
In main function [scanf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm) function with `%s` argument can read entire string. You don't need for-loop to read input string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define NUM_PASSWDS 3

const char* passwd[NUM_PASSWDS] = {
"123foo", "bar456", "bla_blubb"
};
int pwdquery(char pass[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PASSWDS; i++) 
    {
        if (strcmp(pass, passwd[i]) == 0) 
        {
            return 1; // One means currect password
        }
    }
    return 0; // Zero means incorrect password password
}

int main() {
    char a[100];
    printf("Please enter password");
    scanf("%s", a);

    if(pwdquery(a) == 1)
    {
        printf("Password entered is correct");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Password entered is incorrect");
    }
}
```

---

**With custom `strcmp`**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define NUM_PASSWDS 3

const char* passwd[NUM_PASSWDS] = {
"123foo", "bar456", "bla_blubb"
};

//Returns 0 if string don't match else returns 1
int user_strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    size_t str1_size = strlen(str1);
    size_t str2_size = strlen(str2);
    if(str1_size != str2_size)
    {
        return 0; //String are not of same size. The strings won't match.
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < str1_size; i++)
    {
        if(str1[i] != str2[i])
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
int pwdquery(char pass[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PASSWDS; i++) 
    {
        if (user_strcmp(pass, passwd[i]) == 1) 
        {
            return 1; // One means currect password
        }
    }
    return 0; // Zero means incorrect password password
}

int main() {
    char a[100];
    printf("Please enter password");
    scanf("%99s", a);

    if(pwdquery(a) == 1)
    {
        printf("Password entered is correct");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Password entered is incorrect");
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of using strcmp function we are required to make our own function to compare it 
...if you could kindly verfiy the mistake in for the comparison code                                        int cmp(char pass1[], char pass2[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (pass1[i] == pass1[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

Comment: @ShamsMohammed; I have modified my answer for custom `strcmp` function.

Comment: `scanf("%s", a);` -> `scanf("%99s", a);` to prevent undefined behavior on unexpectedly large input. And check the return value in case of input error.

Comment: in `user_strcmp`, you might use `size_t` for the lengths and the index variables. Furthermore it is error prone to use `strcmp` in the function name when the semantics are different from the standard library `strcmp` function. Use `same_strings` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the password comparison function `pwdquery` compares a character and a pointer: this is incorrect. You should use `strcmp` to compare the strings and return a non zero value if one of these comparisons returns `0`.
- in the loop, you ask for the password 3 times, but you only check the password after this loop, hence only test the last one entered.
- `scanf("%s", a)` may cause a buffer overflow if the user enters more than 99 characters without white space. Use `scanf("%99s", a)` to tell `scanf` the maximum number of characters to store into `a` before the null terminator.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_PASSWDS  3

const char *passwd[NUM_PASSWDS] = {
    "123foo", "bar456", "bla_blubb",
};

int pwd_check(const char *pass) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_PASSWDS; i++) {
        if (passwd[i] && strcmp(passwd[i], pass) == 0)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char a[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("Please enter password: ");
        if (scanf("%99s", a) != 1) {
            printf("missing input, aborting\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (pwd_check(a)) {
            printf("correct!\n");
            return 0;
        }
        printf("incorrect password\n");
    }
    printf("too many errors, aborting\n");
    return 1;
}
```